# Generate list of random number using RNGCryptoServiceProvider in range 0 to n

Tags: c#

How to create list of random number with out duplication in c# using `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`

I want to have in range for example 0 to n numbers ?

Comment: @Jon, this is not a duplicate, the post you refer to is using the System.Random class. RNGCryptoServiceProvider has a different interface and will require a very different solution.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: That is not the point. The point is that using crypto-strength randomness to pick *unique* numbers annuls their crypto-strength property. Therefore you should simply e.g. Fischer-Yates shuffle and pick as many (guaranteed unique) numbers as you want; the question is misguided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited: if the problem is to costruct a random value with given number of
digits, the solution could be to assemble the value digit by digit:

```
static RNGCryptoServiceProvider provider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

public static int NextRandomDigit() {
  Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1];

  while (true) {
    provider.GetBytes(bytes);

    // since GetBytes returns value in a range of [0..255], we should skip [250..255]
    // in order to value % 10 being uniformly distributed
    if (bytes[0] >= 250)
      continue;

    return bytes[0] % 10;
  }
}

// Constructing long digit by digit
// Assuming that numberOfDigits is small enough (18 or less) 
// for returning value being of type long
public static long NextRandomLong(int numberOfDigits) {
  long result = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDigits; ++i)
    result = result * 10 + NextRandomDigit();

  return result;
}

// Constructing number in String representation digit by digit
public static String NextRandomString(int numberOfDigits) {
  StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();

  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDigits; ++i)
    Sb.Append((Char) ('0' + NextRandomDigit()));

  return Sb.ToString();
}
```

Be careful: since all digits are equally possible, there will be 
values starting with zero(s) like "0012861542"

Comment: Hi I want to use `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`  for list of random number 

8902347165

1283837881

3338939333
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
8345784213

for each number length have same size if you can show me way thanks.

Comment: @SeeTheWay, you should add the details of what you want to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] Results = new byte[n]
do
{
    yourCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes(Results);
}
while (!Results.Distinct().SequenceEqual(Results))
```